# Application failed codesign verification (-19011)

Tags: ios, code-signing

I met this when archiving my app to upload to iTunes Connect.

I have used Xcode's organizer to upload successfully and the status is : *Waiting For Review*.

I want to know how to fix this warning. Also, with this warning will my app pass the review process?

There are so many answers about this particular problem but not one can fix my problem.

Thank you in advance!

Development Environment: Xcode 4.3.2 and Mac OS X 10.7.4

```
Validate /Users/jxdwinter/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/StarHopeFundingApprovalSystem-azmlbbmdkygsuqbxaoguxikbbnfo/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/StarHopeFundingApprovalSystem/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/StarHopeFundingApprovalSystem.app
cd /Users/jxdwinter/Desktop/StarHopeFundingApprovalSystem
setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
setenv PRODUCT_TYPE com.apple.product-type.application
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/Validation /Users/jxdwinter/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/StarHopeFundingApprovalSystem-azmlbbmdkygsuqbxaoguxikbbnfo/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/StarHopeFundingApprovalSystem/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/StarHopeFundingApprovalSystem.app

warning: Application failed codesign verification.  The signature was invalid, contains disallowed entitlements, or it was not signed with an iPhone Distribution Certificate. (-19011)
Executable=/Users/jxdwinter/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/StarHopeFundingApprovalSystem-azmlbbmdkygsuqbxaoguxikbbnfo/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/StarHopeFundingApprovalSystem/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/StarHopeFundingApprovalSystem.app/StarHopeFundingApprovalSystem
AssertMacros: message,  file: codesign_wrapper.c, line: 554
AssertMacros: profile,  file: codesign_wrapper.c, line: 918
codesign_wrapper-0.7.10: Failed to load provision profile from: /Users/jxdwinter/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/StarHopeFundingApprovalSystem-azmlbbmdkygsuqbxaoguxikbbnfo/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/StarHopeFundingApprovalSystem/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/StarHopeFundingApprovalSy- (null)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exact issue happened to me as well 2 weeks ago my app got rejected because it failed to initialize on review I had to recreate my distribution certificate and resubmit before it was accepted.
Make sure to delete your old certificate from the organizer window in Xcode and click refresh so the certificate is retrieved automatically from iTunes connect.

UPDATE:
This just happened to me now with a second app that I am submitting fixed by shortening the project scheme title and removing all spaces in the title. Try this simple measure before you do anything else.

UPDATE:
The scheme is on the upper left hand corner in Xcode click it > Edit Scheme> Duplicate scheme > change the name of the duplicate to a shorter one

Comment: Hey,Anmar. Will pls tell me the detail about how to shortening the project scheme title? Thank you very much.

Comment: Thx man, just shortening the title of the project name and it works!

Comment: How do you shorten the title? Is there a simple way to edit it?

Comment: The scheme is on the upper left hand corner in Xcode click it > Duplicate scheme > change the name of the duplicate to a shorter one

Answer (score 0):

```
Application failed codesign verification.  The signature was invalid, contains disallowed entitlements, or it was not signed with an iPhone Distribution Certificate.
```

It means, that you have a problem with your distr. certificate. Try to recreate it. Also try to remove entitlements or fix them both in the project and in the provisioning portal, profile. Check, if you sign your release/distribution build correctly.

Comment: I recreate certificate and download the provisioning file for many times, and I'm sure that the setting is right, but there is still this warning. But my app in iTunes Connect status is waiting for review... I don't understand why this warning happened and why I can upload my app to iTunes Connect successfully...